# Replicating Background Behavior From Brawl Stars

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So an interesting problem/question, but I've been trying to replicate this background effect [here (brawl stars)](https://vimeo.com/765466988), with the icons filling the background and moving in chosen direction with a specific speed off the screen.

I've been able to initialize the background tiles/icons to immediately show up when the view is loaded, however I am having trouble timing new tiles/icons to come in at the right time, and at the right speed to look the same. I also don't know if this is the best approach and this just represents my feeble attempt at messing around and trying to replicate this behavior.

Any advice or ideas welcome.

```
func initializeBackgroundTiles()
{
    let itemsPerRow = 4

    let itemHeight = self.frame.width / 7
    let widthBetween = (itemHeight * 2) / 5
    let columnHeight = widthBetween * 4
    
    for column in 0...10 {
        
        for row in 0...5 {
            
            let columnPosition = (columnHeight * CGFloat(column))
            
            let xCalc = CGFloat(
                -(itemHeight + widthBetween) // one row to the left as well
                + (itemHeight * Double(row) + (widthBetween * Double(row))))
            
            let yCalc = (((self.frame.height - itemHeight) - columnPosition * 2) +
                         ((row % 2 == 1 ? columnHeight : 0)))
                    
            let tileSubview = CustomImageView(frame: CGRect(
                x: xCalc,
                y: yCalc,
                width: itemHeight,
                height: itemHeight))
            
            tileSubview.image = UIImage(named: "lightBand")!.withTintColor(.white)
            tileSubview.alpha = 0.04
            ContentView.addSubview(tileSubview)
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 30, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
                
                let newX = ((itemHeight * Double(row)) + (widthBetween * Double(row))) + widthBetween * 3
                let newY = 0 - ((itemHeight + (row % 2 == 0 ? columnHeight : 0)) + columnPosition * 2)
                
                tileSubview.frame = CGRect(
                    x: newX,
                    y: newY,
                    width: itemHeight,
                    height: itemHeight
                )
            } completion: { completed in
                tileSubview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}

func addBackgroundTilesTimer()
{
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 6, target: self, selector: #selector(continueBackgroundTiles), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func continueBackgroundTiles()
{
    // spawn a vertical and horizontal row every x seconds
    let itemHeight = self.frame.width / 7
    let widthBetween = (itemHeight * 2) / 5
    let columnHeight = widthBetween * 4

        
        for row in 0...7 {
            
            let columnPosition = (columnHeight * CGFloat(1))
            
            let xCalc = CGFloat(
                -((itemHeight + widthBetween) * 2) // two buffer rows to the left as well
                + (itemHeight * Double(row) + (widthBetween * Double(row))))
            
            let yCalc = (((self.frame.height - itemHeight) - columnPosition * 2) +
                         ((row % 2 == 1 ? columnHeight : 0)))
                    
            let tileSubview = CustomImageView(frame: CGRect(
                x: xCalc,
                y: yCalc,
                width: itemHeight,
                height: itemHeight))
            
            tileSubview.image = UIImage(named: "lightBand")!.withTintColor(.white)
            tileSubview.alpha = 0.04
            self.ContentView.addSubview(tileSubview)
             
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 30, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
                
                let newX = ((itemHeight * Double(row)) + (widthBetween * Double(row))) + widthBetween * 3
                let newY = 0 - ((itemHeight + (row % 2 == 0 ? columnHeight : 0)) + columnPosition * 2)
                
                tileSubview.frame = CGRect(
                    x: newX,
                    y: newY,
                    width: itemHeight,
                    height: itemHeight
                )
            } completion: { completed in
                tileSubview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share gif with the current behavior?

Comment: It's the same as the brawl stars one to start, but the new ones just come in at the wrong speed from the bottom and its all wonky. I'm just trying to brainstorm a better solution than the makeshift one I'm using right now, or a way that I should approach this.

Comment: Got it, I will upload the code tomorrow when I will get to my laptop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need this but here is the answer. Don't forget to initialize it with the `rect` of view controllers `view`. If you want to rotate it like in brawl stars then just add transform which rotates `TiledBackgroundView`.

```
class TiledBackgroundView: UIView {
    
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    private let vCount = 10
    private let hCount = 5
    private let timeScale = 10
    
    private var itemHeight: CGFloat {
        frame.height / CGFloat(vCount)
    }
    
    private var itemWidth: CGFloat {
        frame.width / CGFloat(hCount)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        initializeBackgroundTiles()
        addBackgroundTilesTimer()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func initializeBackgroundTiles() {
        for column in 0..<hCount {
            for row in 0..<vCount {
                addTile(
                    column: column,
                    row: row
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addBackgroundTilesTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: Double(timeScale), target: self, selector: #selector(continueBackgroundTiles), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func continueBackgroundTiles() {
        for column in 0..<hCount {
            addTile(
                column: column,
                row: vCount
            )
        }
    }
    
    func addTile(
        column: Int,
        row: Int
    ) {
        let x = itemWidth * CGFloat(column)
        let y = itemHeight * CGFloat(row)
        
        let tileSubview = UIImageView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: x,
                y: y,
                width: itemWidth,
                height: itemHeight
            )
        )
        tileSubview.contentMode = .center
        
        tileSubview.image = UIImage(named: "<your_image>")!.withTintColor(.white)
        addSubview(tileSubview)
        
        let duration = CGFloat(timeScale) * (CGFloat(row) + 1)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
            tileSubview.frame.origin = .init(x: x, y: -self.itemHeight)
        } completion: { completed in
            tileSubview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
}
```